# Is HJXDDUDAYIZQRFGSJJ a valid one-time pad encryption of WESTERNENGINEERING?

Tags: encryption, decryption, one-time-pad

How we can check this is valid or not?
As I know in one time pad, we have key to make cipher text from plain-text.

```
WESTERNENGINEERING

HJXDDUDAYIZQRFGSJJ
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they have the same length: **yes**. That's the point of one-time pad. Any ciphertext can be decrypted to everything. You **must** know the correct key to decide which decryption is the correct one.

That's why bruteforcing is useless against a one time pad.

---

In partcular the key: `LFFKDQWLCRDNBPKWD` should do the trick for the pair of plaintext/ciphertext you provided.

Answer (score 4):

If a one-time pad was used, then

```
HJXDDUDAYIZQRFGSJJ
```

could legitimately decrypt to any of these, or 1.0314425e+28 other strings;

```
WESTERNENGINEERING
HARRYPOTTERFOREVER
CHECKPOINTFIREWALL
INSERTYOURTEXTHERE
ANYTHINGWORKS1TIME
```

Without the key there is no way to know what the mapping is.  Even if you reverse a key from what you believe the text to be, unless that key was used twice you cannot know if that's the correct key (which is why they're called one-time pads).